# Total Mass of a Spherical Object

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Consider a spherical galaxy with volumetric mass density, at a distance $s$ from the center, is given by

$$
\rho = \frac{k}{1+s^3}
$$

where $k$ is a constant. Let $k = 25$. Determine the total mass $M$ enclosed within a distance $r$ to the galaxy center (using spherical shells).

I think the total mass, $M$, would be

$$
M = \int_{-r}^r \rho(x)V(x)dr 
$$
Since 
$$
m = \rho V
$$
Then
$$
M = \int_{-r}^r\left(\frac{25}{1+x^3}\right)\left[\frac{4\pi}{3}\left(x^3-R^3\right)\right]dx\\
M = \frac{100\pi}{3}\int_{-r}^r\frac{x^3-R^3}{1+x^3}dx
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
The radius $r$ goes from zero to $R$.
The mass distribution is spherically symmetric, and we want to sum together the masses of the spherical layers.
At radius $r$ the density is $\rho(r)$ and the volume of a thin layer of thickness $dr$ is $4\pi r^2 dr$.
Thus
$$
M=\int_0^R\rho(r)4\pi r^2dr.
$$
The point is to use $m=\rho V$ for each spherical layer separately, since it does not hold for objects with varying density.